# How to parse data from Firebase array to splited page?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

So I have this route for show the Test section that has 24 questions. I got my question database on Firebase which I call them this way:

```
  .controller('testCtrl', function($scope,$rootScope,$ionicSideMenuDelegate,fireBaseData,$state,$firebaseObject,
                                $ionicHistory,$firebaseArray,sharedCartService,sharedUtils) {


//Check if user already logged in
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    $scope.user_info=user; //Saves data to user_info
  }else {

    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft(); //To close the side bar
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(false);  // To remove the sidemenu white space

    $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
      historyRoot: true
    });
    $rootScope.extras = false;
    sharedUtils.hideLoading();
    $state.go('tabsController.login', {}, {location: "replace"});

  }
});

// On Loggin in to menu page, the sideMenu drag state is set to true
$ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(false);
  $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft(false);
$rootScope.extras=true;

// When user visits A-> B -> C -> A and clicks back, he will close the app instead of back linking
$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(ev) {
  if(ev.targetScope !== $scope){
    $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
    $ionicHistory.clearCache();
  }
});



  $scope.loadQuest = function() {
  sharedUtils.showLoading();
  //HERE I CALL MY QUESTION DATABASE
  $scope.pertanyaans=$firebaseArray(fireBaseData.refPertanyaaans());

  sharedUtils.hideLoading();
}





$scope.showQuestInfo=function (id) {

};})
```

and this is the interface code

```
        <ion-view style="" class=" " id="test" title="Test">
        <ion-content class="has-header" padding="false"  ng-init="loadQuest()"  >
    <br>
    <div ng-repeat="pertanyaan in pertanyaans" >
    <div class="card-quest">
    <div class="item item-wrap">
      <div class="item item-text-wrap">
    <b>{{pertanyaan.nama}}
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

        </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
    <ion-view style="" class=" " id="test" title="Test">
        <ion-content class="has-header" padding="false"  ng-init="loadQuest()"  > <div ng-repeat="pertanyaan in pertanyaans" >
    <div class="card-quest">
    <div class="item item-wrap">
      <div class="item item-text-wrap">
    <b>{{pertanyaan.nama}}
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

        </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
```

And here are my database in Firebase

```
{
  "item1" : {
    "nama" : "Perkataan yang saya sampaikan dapat diingat dan berkesan untuk orang lain.",
    "nilai" : "item7"
  },
  "item10" : {
    "nama" : "Pada kebanyakan situasi sosial/umum, saya mengambil kesempatan untuk berbicara.",
    "nilai" : "item3"
  },
  "item11" : {
    "nama" : "Seringnya saya bertindak secara fisik dan lisan tentang apa yang ingin saya komunikasikan.",
    "nilai" : "item4"
  },
  "item12" : {
    "nama" : "Ketika saya tersinggung pada pembicaraan yang panas, saya sulit untuk menahan diri saya sendiri.",
    "nilai" : "item1"
  },
  "item13" : {
    "nama" : "Saya meminta bukti atas apa yang orang jelaskan seperti dokumen dan sumbernya.",
    "nilai" : "item9"
  },
  "item14" : {
    "nama" : "Saya mencoba untuk mengambil alih hal-hal ketika saya dengan orang-orang.",
    "nilai" : "item3"
  },
  "item15" : {
    "nama" : "Cara saya mengatakan sesuatu biasanya meninggalkan kesan pada orang.",
    "nilai" : "item7"
  },
  "item16" : {
    "nama" : "Setiap kali saya berkomunikasi, saya cenderung sangat mendorong/memotivasi orang-orang.",
    "nilai" : "item6"
  },
  "item17" : {
    "nama" : "Saya aktif menggunakan banyak ekspresi wajah dalam berkomunikasi.",
    "nilai" : "item5"
  },
  "item18" : {
    "nama" : "Biasanya saya terbuka mengungkapkan perasaan dan emosi saya.",
    "nilai" : "item8"
  },
  "item19" : {
    "nama" : "Biasanya saya tidak akan banyak menceritakan tentang diri saya sampai saya mengenal mereka dengan baik.",
    "nilai" : "item8"
  },
  "item2" : {
    "nama" : "Saya sering mengucap “terimakasih” atas pertolongan orang lain agar terlihat ramah.",
    "nilai" : "item6"
  },
  "item20" : {
    "nama" : "Saya terlihat gugup saat berbicara depan umum.",
    "nilai" : "item10"
  },
  "item21" : {
    "nama" : "Saya selalu merasa mudah untuk berkomunikasi secara langsung dengan orang asing.",
    "nilai" : "item11"
  },
  "item22" : {
    "nama" : "Saya akan dengan mudah berkomunikasi dalam kelompok kecil yang berisikan orang asing.",
    "nilai" : "item11"
  },
  "item23" : {
    "nama" : "Saya merasa sangat mudah untuk mempertahankan perbincangan dengan lawan jenis yang baru saya temui.",
    "nilai" : "item11"
  },
  "item24" : {
    "nama" : "Jika dalam lingkungan dari 6 orang yang acak termasuk saya, saya lebih baik dari (.......) orang tersebut.",
    "nilai" : "item11"
  },
  "item3" : {
    "nama" : "Saya dengan sigap mengatakan ketidaksetujuan saya terhadap pendapat seseorang.",
    "nilai" : "item1"
  },
  "item4" : {
    "nama" : "Saya selalu dapat menyampaikan kembali apa yang orang maksud.",
    "nilai" : "item2"
  },
  "item5" : {
    "nama" : "Saya berbicara dengan sangat rinci.",
    "nilai" : "item9"
  },
  "item6" : {
    "nama" : "Saat berada di bawah tekanan saya justru cenderung berbicara dengan santai.",
    "nilai" : "item10"
  },
  "item7" : {
    "nama" : "Biasanya saya akan dengan sengaja bereaksi sedemikian rupa sehingga orang tahu bahwa saya mendengarkan mereka.",
    "nilai" : "item2"
  },
  "item8" : {
    "nama" : "Sudah menjadi kebiasaan saya untuk menyisipkan anekdot dan lelucon ketika berkomunikasi dengan orang lain.",
    "nilai" : "item4"
  },
  "item9" : {
    "nama" : "Saya cenderung untuk selalu menggunakan bahasa tubuh ketika berkomunikasi.",
    "nilai" : "item5"
  }
}
```

This is how the questions show up

[image: IMAGE: this is how the questions show up]

but those used to be split in different pages.

*pertanyaan* is Bahasa, same as *question* in English.
*pertanyaans* = *questions*

Comment: which version of firebase are you using ? and can you share `fireBaseData.refPertanyaaans()`.

Comment: firebase 3, I am okay with that, I just can't make those questions split in different section/page like using index

Comment: Nice..No no i mean the code for `fireBaseData.refPertanyaaans()`